# webscraping a pdf file using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I've been web scraping articles in R  from the Oxford journals and want to grab the full text of specific articles. All articles have a pdf link to them so I've been trying to pull the pdf link and scrape the entire text onto a csv. The full text should all fit into 1 row however the output in the csv file shows one article of 11 rows. How can I fix this issue?

The code is below:

```
####install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
#for Fulltext to read pdf
####install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)


fullText <- function(parsedDocument){
  endLink <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node('.article-pdfLink') %>% html_attr('href')
  frontLink <- "https://academic.oup.com"
  #link  of pdf
  pdfLink <- paste(frontLink,endLink,sep = "")
  #extract full text  from pdfLink
  pdfFullText <- pdf_text(pdfLink)
  fulltext <- paste(pdfFullText, sep = "\n")
  return(fulltext)
}
#############################################

#main function with input as parameter year
testFullText <- function(DOIurl){
  parsedDocument <- read_html(DOIurl)
  DNAresearch <- data.frame()
  allData <- data.frame("Full Text" = fullText(parsedDocument), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  DNAresearch <-  rbind(DNAresearch, allData)
  write.csv(DNAresearch, "DNAresearch.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
testFullText("https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this task.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

df <- data.frame(
  # you have a data.frame with a column where there are links to html research articles
  links_to_articles = c("https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026", "https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm027")
) %>%
  # telling R to process each row separately (it is useful because functions such as read_html process one link rather than a vector of links)
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    pdf_link =  read_html(links_to_articles) %>%
      html_node('.article-pdfLink') %>%
      html_attr('href') %>%
      paste0("https://academic.oup.com", .),
    articles_txt = pdf_text(pdf_link) %>%
      paste0(collapse = " ")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# writing the csv
df %>%
  write_csv(file = "DNAresearch.csv")
```

Using your code, I would do:

```
####install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
#for Fulltext to read pdf
####install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)


fullText <- function(parsedDocument){
  endLink <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node('.article-pdfLink') %>% html_attr('href')
  frontLink <- "https://academic.oup.com"
  #link  of pdf
  pdfLink <- paste(frontLink,endLink,sep = "")
  #extract full text  from pdfLink
  pdfFullText <- pdf_text(pdfLink)
  fulltext <- paste(pdfFullText, collapse = " ") # here I changed sep to collapse
  return(fulltext)
}
#############################################

#main function with input as parameter year
testFullText <- function(DOIurl){
  parsedDocument <- read_html(DOIurl)
  DNAresearch <- data.frame()
  allData <- data.frame("Full Text" = fullText(parsedDocument) %>% str_squish(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # here I used str_squish to remove extra spaces
  DNAresearch <-  rbind(DNAresearch, allData)
  write.csv(DNAresearch, "DNAresearch.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
testFullText("https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026")
```

Comment: well, you've beaten me by one minute! :)

Comment: It's not a race :-)

Comment: thanks for  the quick response, I tried `sep = "\n"` but it didn't work. My csv file is still outputting many rows instead of one row for each scraped document

Comment: Could you please share link to a PDF that you have trouble parsing? Your example code is not reproducible/complete I am afraid.

Comment: yes no problem I will update the code that is doing the parse

Comment: The program works from a parameter year inputted in` findURL`

Comment: I would like to kindly point out that if you want to increase your chance of getting help, you should try to share code that sufficiently demonstrates the problem, but at the same time is short. Going through 100 lines of code that mostly do not have anything to do with the actual problem may be off putting for some people.

Comment: Edited my answer.